# It is possible to Stream data from beam (Scio) to an S3 bucket?

Tags: java, scala, amazon-s3, sbt

Currently, I'm working on a project which extracts data from a BigQuery table using Scio in Scala.

I'm able to extract and ingest the data into ElasticSearch, but I'm trying to do the same but using an S3 bucket as storage.

Certainly, I'm able to write the data into a txt file using the method `saveAsTextFile`, and then upload it from my machine to the s3 bucket adding the correct libraries into sbt.

However, I don't know if it is possible to write a `saveCustomOutput` code to write the data right away to S3, instead of using a local storage.

Comment: BG table? Scollecton? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake while writing the question, I was referring to Big Query tables and the Scio libraries

Comment: Do you have to use beam? Or is the problem we want data from BG inside S3? there are smpler ways

Comment: I want to orchestrate the extraction and transformation from different sources (BQ and pub/sub) using beam + dataflow, and finally store the results in csv format on the S3 side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but instead of using an S3 bucket as LZ, I set a Kinesis Data stream. By adding a Kinesis event over a Lambda function, it was possible to stream the data into an S3 bucket

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).